# Search highlighted text on Google using keyboard

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome on Mac OS. I frequently Google Search words as I'm reading articles by highlighting the word (or block of multiple words)---call it X---pressing right-click, and then pressing "Search Google for 'X'".    I'm looking for a way, after highlighting, to just use the keyboard to search Google for "X".

How do I do this?

Comment: If you have a 10-key pad you could enable Mouse Keys, then use Ctrl/5 to do the right click, then down arrow to highlight & Enter or Cmd/Enter to search… but it does seem a lot of faff & also would fight with screen switching keys if you use multiple Spaces. idk how [or if] Mouse Keys works on a laptop keyboard.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a 10-key pad?

Comment: I also have Windows and any comments about how this would be possible on Windows would also be appreciated.

Comment: It would be an awesome addition on Win10 as well!